# How to switch navbar-default To navbar-inverse In xs View in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to switch `navbar-default` to `navbar-inverse` in xs View in Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the default Bootstrap behaviors.

### Option #1 (js)

Use jQuery to detect when you should use `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse` :

```
function refreshNavbar() {
    $('.navbar')
        .removeClass('navbar-default navbar-inverse')
        .addClass($(window).width() <= 768 
                      ? 'navbar-inverse' 
                      : 'navbar-default');
}

$(window).on('resize', refreshNavbar); // on window.resize
refreshNavbar(); // on window.load
```

### Option #2 (no-js)

Duplicate the `navbar-inverse` code and make your own `navbar-autoinverse` :

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-autoinverse" role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>
```

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-autoinverse {
      background-color: #222222;
      border-color: #080808;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-brand {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-brand:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-text {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #080808;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
      color: #444444;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: #333333;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
      background-color: #333333;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-form {
      border-color: #101010;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #080808;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret {
      border-top-color: #ffffff;
      border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
      border-top-color: #999999;
      border-bottom-color: #999999;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
      border-top-color: #ffffff;
      border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
        border-color: #080808;
    }
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #999999;
    }
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #080808;
    }
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover
    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
        color: #444444;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-link {
      color: #999999;
    }

    .navbar-autoinverse .navbar-link:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any way to do this with Bootstrap out of the box. Your best is to use Javascript to switch the classes. You should be able to use jQuery to do something like:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
  $('#NAVBAR_ID').addClass('navbar-inverse');
} else {
  $('#NAVBAR_ID').removeClass('navbar-inverse');
}
```